# What does % mean in a file

Tags: python, bash, eof

I am getting a '%' character when I cat the file.  When I open this using sublime text or vim, this '%' character does not show up.  I am using the following code to generate my json.txt file:

```
import json

filename = "json.txt"


with open(filename, "r+") as f:
    x = [1, 'simple', 'list']
    json.dumps(x)
    json.dump(x, f)
```

Comment: what you want is to stop seeing that `%` when you run `cat`, don't you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run `cat` and see `%`, as DroidX86 has said, it means that there is no a new line at the end of the file, you can avoid this problem using the following code:

```
import json

filename = "json.txt"

with open(filename, "r+") as f:
    x = [1, 'simple', 'list']
    print(json.dumps(x, indent=4),file=f)
```

Now, if you run `cat`, you no longer will see the `%` since the function `print` adds a new line for you.

Answer (score 1):

No new line at the end of the file. The `%` is the end of the file.